# Moving from Nginx Ingress to HPProxy on openshift

Tags: nginx, openshift, haproxy, nginx-ingress

I had installed nginx with below to fwd outside traffic coming on port 162 to service/port running on a pod.

helm install stable/citm-ingress --name=nginx --set udp.162=default/myapp:1620

Now I need to use HPProxy and wondering how to achieve same. If someone has done something similar, pls let me know. I am new to Openshift.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use UDP with OpenShift Router (HAProxy) because haproxy have not implemented UDP.
You can read more about this topic in this issue [UDP Loadbalancing](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/62)

I suggest to use [NodePort](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-nodeport.html) for the udp ingress.

Comment: it is for outside UDP traffic coming on port 162 and needs to be processed by service running on pod.

Comment: yes. therfore you need to use NodePort to reache the pod via UDP

Comment: @user1731045 you can also use [externalIPs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-externalip.html)